# Making a layout big as the real content, not the background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relativeLayout with two children: two textviews, one below the other. The `relativeLayout` has `wrap_content` as the height rule.

Now this `relative_layout` has a background that is `800x500` and so it takes this `500` height pixel as its height. I have to crop it, giving something like `150dp` as a height rule to accommodate the two textviews without wasting way more space than needed.

How can I use that background, but make the height of the `relativeLayout` a real `wrap_content`?

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="130dp" /*if i have wrap_content here it take 500px as height */
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_background2" // 800x500>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CounterMechanicsTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:text="@string/mechanics" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CounterMechanics"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/CounterMechanicsTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="@string/mechanics" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe change the background picture (resize it, before to use it), so it can be as height as the two `TextViews` together ?

Comment: I would like to keep things relative, a texture if 800x500 allows me to reuse it, if i'm able to resize it from the code part.

Comment: Yes you can resize it, then assign this to a drawable resource (you can even resize it inthe code based on the cumulative size of the TextViews) and set is as a background resource to the RelativeLayout. Try it and paste the result you got, or shall I help you with that?

Comment: ah ok, i did not get you the first time sorry. I'll try that sure, and of course if you would like an accepted answer write that down, so other people aswell could use your method. 

Thanks =)

Comment: .wrapping both textviews inside a vertical linear layout with wrap content as height is no option?

Comment: @ChristianR. - not an option, except in case when the combined height of the two textviews is exactly 500px.

Comment: @g00dy i made it, want me to answer my question or you wanna do that ?

Thanks again by the way, today i learned a new thing :)

The only bad thing is that `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated :(

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)` is deprecated and replaced by `.setBackground(Drawable))`, so you can see the example below.

Comment: yep i noticed, but `setBackground()` is for API 16+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's one approach:

```
    TextView CounterMechanicsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CounterMechanicsTitle);
    TextView CounterMechanics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CounterMechanics);
    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.counter_background2);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mid);

    int heightOfTextViews = CounterMechanicsTitle.getHeight() + CounterMechanics.getHeight();
    //Now you have the height of the two TextViews

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
    // Scale the drawable to heightOfTextViews *1.6 x heightOfTextViews, so to be scaled properly
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, heightOfTextViews*1.6, heightOfTextViews, true));

rl.setBackground(d);
    //Optional 
    //rl.getLayoutParams().height = heightOfTextViews;
    //rl.getLayoutParams().width = heightOfTextViews*1.6;
```

See if this fixes it.