# How to scale image relative to the screen size?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapimage

i am making an android app in which i scale the bitmap using 
   `bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 150, 150, true);`

this image looks good enough on a mobile with big screen ...but it goes out of proportion when used on a phone with small size .....any one knows the solution for it?

Comment: There's a similar question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835318/making-a-layout-big-as-his-real-content-not-his-background/17837371#17837371

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410364/how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the image size in dp, just like you do in XML. To do the conversion from dp to pixels you can use something like:

```
float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ht, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, wt, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

For your particular case use:

```
float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and scale the bitmap with ht_px and wt_px. You might need to change 150 to 75.

Comment: yeah i was thinking the same .....but    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 150, 150, true);
doesn't accept values in dp.....

and sorry i cannot understand your sloution,can you please elaborate ?

Comment: well i had no problem with ht,wt,..... i wanted to ask whats this typedValue thing???

Comment: "Container for a dynamically typed data value. Primarily used with Resources for holding resource values." You can check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html

Answer (score 4):

take height and width of screen and calculate your size

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);
    int screenWidth = display.widthPixels;
    int  screenHeight = display.heightPixels;
```

like you want to show your bitmap half of the screen then-

```
 bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, true);
```

calculate it according to you requirement.

Comment: whats getWindowManager()...there seems to be no import for this

Comment: more info read this-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html